# Can I use HTTPS 404 header?

Tags: https, http-headers, http-status-code-404

Is it a good solution if I put to my 404.php file this header?

```
<?php
header("HTTPS/1.1 404 oldal nem található");
?>
```

(Instead of [...]HTTP/1.1[...]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better alternatives are available according to use cases, this [includes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

1. To override HTTP status messages for clients that are still using HTTP/1.0

```php
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 404 Not Found");
```

2. To use the default message

```php
http_response_code(404);
```

It's okay to use direct string.